# How can I debug webpack bundle file error and find exact error in bundle that consists thousand no. of lines in reactJs

Tags: debugging, reactjs, webpack, bundle

I want to find exact error in my program, where is error occurring in real time. I have been facing problem to detect error as It only shows bundle file that have thousand no. of lines. That is next to impossible to go through all the code at once. Please provide solution If you have. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In webpack config file , check `debug` is true :

```
{
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: ...

....
}
```

Comment: People keep leaving out the context, where do you put these? What does the object `{...}` belong to? module.exports.{....} ?

Edit: Debug option was removed in 2.0.0 lol

Comment: Is there any new solution to this? Debug is not available anymore

Answer (score 0):

Please use the devtool option of webpack.

Look at it
https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool

I suggest use eval like below

```
devtool: debug ? "eval" : null,
```

It will minimize your code and show you where the error is actually.For more info refer the link i have shared.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call webpack function, you can console.log the stats :

```
webpack(config, function (err, stats) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.log(stats.toString())
})
```

Maybe it could help you